# drag and drop with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

what is the problem with the following code?

see here: http://jsfiddle.net/xKcAu/

JS:

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    $('#diag1').draggable();
    $('#diag1').css('background-color', '#f4f');
    $('#diag1').width('100px');
    $('#diag1').height('50px');

    $('#cnt1').css('background-color', '#4ff');
    $('#cnt1').width('300px');
    $('#cnt1').height('300px');

    $('#cnt1').droppable({
        drop: function( event, ui ) {                
            $(this).append(ui.draggable);
        }
    });

});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="cnt1">ddd</div>
<div id="diag1">Dialog 1</div>
```

If I drop the smaller div on the bigger one it hides away. Why?

Comment: Looks like a `z-index` issue.

Comment: this line: $(this).append(ui.draggable); --- also take a look about chaining in jquery you dont need to define the selector for jquery functions all the time. you can do $('.selector').css().parent().find().whatever()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing really other than you've coded it so that when the div is dropped, it becomes a child of the larger div and then based on the positioning it ends up off screen. See what happens when you reposition the larger div: **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xKcAu/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
#​diag1{
    position:absolute;
}
```

or add

```
$('#diag1').css('position', 'absolute');
```

I am not 100% sure , is this what you are looking for ?

[http://jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/xKcAu/2/)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't dissapear. It is appended to where you dropped, but it keeps the old position values and ends offscreen. 
You should try using `position: absolute` on `diag1`, so the droppable doesn't use `position: relative`. Now the position coordinates are always going to be measured against the top left of the document, instead of the container.

Answer (score 0):

if all you want to do is keep the draggable in view, then just remove the following

```
$(this).append(ui.draggable);
```

as mentioned the append and positioning is causing the issue.